# Issue with a SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to android development and I have a problem with databases.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me!

This is the error I am receiving:

```
12-05 19:36:49.029 9919-9919/uk.ac.acnh572city.movieapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: jsonResults
```

My code:

```
    package uk.ac.acnh572city.movieapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
* Created by Amir on 29/11/2015.
*/
public class ResultsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movieinfo.db";
public String TABLE_TITLE = "results_dat" +
        "abase";
public static final String COLUMN_JSON = "jsonResults";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "keyword";
public ResultsDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 6);
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_TITLE+ " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " TEXT " + COLUMN_JSON + " TEXT )";
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE " +TABLE_TITLE+ " IF EXISTS");
}
public void addResult(String keyword, String jsonResults) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_ID, keyword);
    cv.put(COLUMN_JSON, jsonResults);
    db.insert(TABLE_TITLE, null, cv);
    db.close();
}

public String displayResults(String keyword) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+COLUMN_JSON+" FROM "+TABLE_TITLE+" WHERE "+COLUMN_ID+" = '"+keyword+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String result = null;

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        result = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return result;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a comma:

```
final String TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_TITLE+ " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " TEXT " + COLUMN_JSON + " TEXT )";
```

should be

```
final String TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_TITLE+ " ("+ COLUMN_ID + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_JSON + " TEXT )";
```

---

**[EDIT]**

I discovered another issue (2 issues in a single statement):

```
db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE " +TABLE_TITLE+ " IF EXISTS");
```

has to be

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_TITLE);
```

You added an extra underscore between the keywords DROP and TABLE and misplaced the table name before the IF EXISTS clause.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input, I corrected it however I am still having the same error.

Comment: So, what? Remove it from the emulator. Which is the same thing as removing it from your device.

Comment: Many thanks MrFrank, it works now!! What do I do in return now?

Comment: I would check if the cursor is null, by simply adding a condition (`if (cursor != null){...}`). And I would use column names instead of column indexes.

Comment: Alright thank you  I will add that to my code! I really hope I will be able to get the hang of this soon.